# Trouble assigning JTextField to GridLayout

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, actionlistener

I have three different classes that handels my GUI components. My main GUI class starts a class that creates sidebar and the other holds a textarea using GridLayout.

This is my main GUI class

```
public class Gui extends JFrame {

    private TextPanel textPanel;
    private Sidebar sidebar;

    public Gui() {
        super("Oblig 5");

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        textPanel = new TextPanel();
        sidebar   = new Sidebar(textPanel);

        add(sidebar, BorderLayout.WEST);
        add(textPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        ...
    }
}
```

My sidebar class has a JButton that sets addActionListener() to the textarea in the other class.
Sidebarclass:

```
public class Sidebar extends JPanel {

    private JButton next;
    private TextPanel panel;
    ...

    FormPanel(TextPanel panel) {
            this.panel = panel;
            ...
            next = new JButton("Next");
            next.addActionListener(panel);
            ...
            add(next, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            ...
    }
}
```

I believe my TextPanel class is where the problem is as I've manage to write to the terminal when the JButton next is clicked, but not write to the GUI screen

```
public class TextPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    ...

    public TextPanel() {
        setLayout(new GridLayout(emptyBoard.length,emptyBoard.length));
    }


    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        nextBoard(container.getBoard());
    }


    public void nextBoard(Square[][] sudokuboard) {
        // I've tried writing out sudokuboard
        // to the terminal, which works fine

        for(int i=0; i<sudokuboard.length; i++) {
            north = 1; west = 1; south = 1; east = 1;
            if(i%rows == 0 && i > 0) {
                    north = 6;
            }

            for(int j=0; j<sudokuboard[i].length; j++) {
                west = 1;
                if(j%columns == 0 && j > 0) {
                    west = 6;
                }

                JTextField square = new JTextField();
                square.setFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, 32));
                square.setText(""+sudokuboard[i][j].getValue());
                square.setEditable(false);
                square.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(north,west,south,east,Color.black));

                if((i/rows + j/columns) % 2 == 0) {
                    square.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
                }

                add(square);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm fairly new with GUI so this might seem like a easy problem to solve, but I've been pulling my hair for a while now...
As I've said, I mange to write nextBoard(Square[][] sudokuboard) to terminal, but so far not to the GUI screen. Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).

Comment: May be problem in adding components to visible component(you can try to add `revalidate();repaint();` at the end of `nextBoard` method). Also post MCVE as recommended by AndrewThompson.

Comment: I thought about posting a MCVE instead, but I got 15 classes that needs to work together for the GUI to work. Didn't want to scare commenters away!

Comment: @alex2410 `revalidate();repaint();` worked perfect! Just one thing.. Now every time I call `nextBoard` the board get added next to the previous one. Any more help?

Comment: You never remove previously added components in `nextBoard(...)`.

Comment: Seems that will be better for you to use [`JTable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) instead of `JTextField`s.

Comment: `"... but I got 15 classes that needs to work together for the GUI to work. Didn't want to scare commenters away!"` -- please re-read the [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) link. If you created this thing correctly, you wouldn't be scaring anyone away because the code you would post would have only 20 to 50 lines in it at most. Yes, it's a lot of effort to create one of these guys, but it is effort well spent. Up to you.